# I need to understand the difference between these two approaches for calculating probability

Tags: probability, self-study

> There are five empty boxes. Balls are placed independently one after
> another in randomly selected boxes. Find the probability that the
> fourth ball is the first to be placed in an occupied box.

**I can think of one way of solving this problem as:**

Placing the first ball in a box will always be unoccupied (hence the probability 1)

Secondly, the ball should be placed in an unoccupied box, so $\frac 4 5$ as there are only 4 box left.

Similarly, the third ball should be placed in an unoccupied box which means we have 3 boxes left, hence probability $\frac{3}{5}$

Now, so far we have occupied 3 boxes so, the fourth ball should be placed in one of the occupied 3 boxes, and the probability for this is $\frac{3}{5}$

All above events must occur, so the final probability is 4/5∗3/5∗3/5=36/125.

I got this answer and this matches with my booklet.

**Another approach for solving this problem**

I have in total $5$ boxes. I know that so far I have placed 4 balls in these 5 boxes. So, the total number of ways to do that is $5^4$.

I need to have one of the box contain 2 balls. So, remaining, 4 boxes must contain other 2 which can happen in $4\choose2$ $4^2$ ways. Hence, the final probability is: $\frac{{4\choose2}4^2}{5^4}$.

My question is that why is this answer not consistent with the previous approach. Is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second approach, you mix *ordered* and *unordered* (i.e. *distinguishable* and *indistinguishable*) things (balls, boxes).

> I have in total $5$ boxes. I know that so far I have placed 4 balls in these 5 boxes. So, the total number of ways to do that is $5^4$.

Sure, but it means that **you supposed the balls and boxes are *labeled (ordered, distinguishable)***:

[image]

and — as an example — the configuration
$$
1 \mapsto \color{red}A\\
2 \mapsto \color{blue}B\\
3 \mapsto C\\
4 \mapsto C\\
$$
is for you different from

$$
1 \mapsto \color{blue}B\\
2 \mapsto \color{red}A\\
3 \mapsto C\\
4 \mapsto C\\
$$

> I need to have one of the box contain 2 balls.

Sure, but **which one** of the 5 *labeled* boxes? And **which** of the first 3 *numbered* balls you put to it as the first ball? There are $\color{red}{(5\times 3)}$ possibilities!

> ... So, remaining, 4 boxes must contain other 2 which can happen in $4\choose2$ $4^2$ ways.

Sure, only your calculation is somewhat strange:

- $4\choose2$ is OK (all possible pairs of remaining boxes), but
- **the second multiplier is simply 2,**

  because there are exactly $2$ possibilities how to put the other 2 balls individually into a particular pair of boxes:

  - ball $x$ into box $X$ and ball $y$ into box $Y$, or
  - ball $x$ into box $Y$ and ball $y$ into box $X$.

As a result you have $\color{blue}{\left({4\choose 2} \times 2\right)} $ choices for the remaining 4 boxes and the remaining 2 balls.

Now your result will be correct, as the numerator of your final fraction is $\color{red}{(5 \times 3)} \times \color{blue}{\left({4\choose 2} \times 2\right)}$.

Comment: You explained it really well. Thank you so much.

Comment: @userNoOne, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In the second approach, possibilities include not only the fourth ball in the occupied box but also the others, e.g. balls 2 and 3. An correct example way of calculating by counting is:

- First choose three boxes, and put the balls into them in some order: ${5\choose 3}3!$
- Pick one of the occupied boxes and put the fourth one: ${3 \choose 1}$

That makes $$\frac{5\times 4 \times 3\times 3}{5^4}=\frac{36}{125}$$

Comment: I understand @gunes, Thank you so much